# IE hangs in "Getting File Information" while downloading file

Tags: internet-explorer, download, freeze

Internet Explorer 8.0 hangs in "Getting File Information" while downloading file.

What could it be? I can download this same file from FireFox.

Answer (score 1):

One solution to this problem is to go to Tools, Internet Options, then advanced and untick the "Do not save encrypted pages to disk" option.

Answer (score 1):

Often, this happens because your Internet Explorer has opened the maximum number of HTTP connections it is permitted to open to a single server.  In IE6, by default (assuming no registry hack to override) the HTTP connection limit is 2 per server.  So, if you wanted to download 3 files and right-clicked each to "Save As", the first two would prompt to save and then download simultaneously, whereas the third would be blocked until one of the first two completed.  In IE8, the connection limit has been increased to 6 per host.

Answer (score 0):

Smart Screen filter can cause this, i guess.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before. Turned out to be bad MTU setting on the NIC.

Answer (score 0):

First thing i would try is run Internet Explorer in "No-addons" mode.

Answer (score 0):

You also might want to check your AV software. IE may be waiting on it to finish scanning the file (maybe the file is large) before it copies it to the directory of your choice. you may try to disable the AV software and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by deleting Google Toolbar from my system.